# PuppeteerSharp in IIS - ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Trying to use PuppeteerSharp in our ASP.NET Web Forms application to generate a PDF and while it works fine locally I receive the below error when deploying to an IIS server.

[image]

One thing I do notice is that a ZIP file with zero bytes called download-Win64-706915.zip is created.

My code is as follows

```
var url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnrolmentFormUrl"] + "?code=" + code;

var fileName = "enrolment" + $"{DateTime.Now:__ddMMyyyyhhmmssfff}" + ".pdf";

var output = Config.attachmentPath + fileName;                     

var browserFetcher = new BrowserFetcher(new BrowserFetcherOptions
{
    Path = Config.attachmentPath
});;

await browserFetcher.DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultRevision).ConfigureAwait(false);
var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
{
    Headless = true,
    TransportFactory = AspNetWebSocketTransport.AspNetTransportFactory,
    ExecutablePath = browserFetcher.RevisionInfo(BrowserFetcher.DefaultRevision).ExecutablePath
}).ConfigureAwait(false);

var pdfOptions = new PdfOptions
{
    Format = PaperFormat.A4,
    PreferCSSPageSize = true
};

var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
await page.GoToAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
await page.PdfAsync(output, pdfOptions).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to the fact that the server being deployed to did not have internet access and PuppeteerSharp was looking to download Chromium resolved by specifying a local execution path.

ExecutablePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

Revised code below

```
var url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnrolmentFormUrl"] + "?code=" + code;

var fileName = "enrolment" + $"{DateTime.Now:__ddMMyyyyhhmmssfff}" + ".pdf";

var output = Config.attachmentPath + fileName;                     

var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
{
    Headless = true,
    TransportFactory = AspNetWebSocketTransport.AspNetTransportFactory,
    ExecutablePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
}).ConfigureAwait(false);

var pdfOptions = new PdfOptions
{
    Format = PaperFormat.A4,
    PreferCSSPageSize = true
};

var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
await page.GoToAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
await page.PdfAsync(output, pdfOptions).ConfigureAwait(false);
```