# Why is Puppeteer not displayed as a child process on IIS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, iis, puppeteer, child-process

I have a node.js server which runs a child process on the server when the user requests.
This child process is managed by npm package '[child_process](https://www.npmjs.com/package/child_process)' and running a '[Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md)' script.
The whole process works as expected on local.
The problem is when I check it on the server, and then - the process IS executed and logs are printed, BUT **I don't see the browser of puppeteer even though it's in headless false**.
The server uses IIS and I suspect that maybe it's related.

p.s. I also tried the npm package '[execa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/execa)' for the execution of the child process, and nothing changed.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Is there any error message ? Could you please use [FRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) to check if there is any error message ?

Comment: No error message. As I said the logs from the child process (the Puppeteer script) are printed. Moreover, I can see the Chromium in Task Manager. I think the problem is that it's running on other user (the one that represents the server domain, and not the one I log as a windows user).

Comment: Could you please check if your problem similar with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62426256/puppeteersharp-in-iis) and check if the solution in the post can help your problem ?